# Where to check for cookie in MVC3 app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I have an MVC3 web app which is effectively 'bolted on' to a classic ASP website (i.e old pages are classic asp, new pages are ASP.Net MVC). 
The site requires the user to log in, so to protect the new MVC pages, I check for a cookie and use the id to retrieve session data from the database which has been created by the classic ASP login page.

Because the user can switch between old & new pages, amd I'm not sharing session data across the 2 apps, I check for the cookie & retrieve data every request in my action method called LogIn:

```
public PartialViewResult LogIn()
        {
            var cookieId = DecodeCookieId(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["cookiename"].Value);

            LoggedInViewModel viewModel = new LoggedInViewModel
            {
                Session = sessionRepository.Sessions.FirstOrDefault(s => s.GGAPSession_ID == cookieId)
            };
            return PartialView(viewModel);
        }
```

This passes data to a ViewModel which displays the logged in username at the top of every MVC page, which is why I thought it would be a good place to do the checking.

The problem occurs when I try modify LogIn() to check for the cookie & redirect if not found:

```
public ActionResult LogIn()
{
   if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["cookiename"] != null)
  {
     //  same method contents as above
  }
  else
  {
    return Redirect("http://localhost/index.asp");
  }
}
```

I get a 'Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions' which I understand, but how do I get round this?  Should I be doing the cookie checking elsewhere?  And where should I be doing the session management?

Comment: is your mvc site and asp site under the same domain?

Comment: The MVC site is a subdomian of the asp site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use a global action filter in you mvc site to do this.it's a general principal stated in book 《ASP.NET MVC in Action》. Do your retrieve in

```
OnActionExecuting
```

if cookie exists. otherwise,

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("http://localhost/index.asp")
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Description

Right, you can use `HttpContext.Response.Redirect` to solve this.

#### Sample

Change

```
return Redirect("http://localhost/index.asp");
```

to

```
HttpContext.Response.Redirect("http://localhost/index.asp");
return EmptyResult();
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - HttpResponse.Redirect Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)